# Move view when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

On the screen, I have several test fields for registration. So that the keyboard does not overlap the fields, I change the constraint. But there was a problem. These fields rise on large screens where this is not required. How can I get rid of it and change the constraint when it is really necessary.

**ViewController.swift**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        var keyboardHeight = CGFloat(0.0)

        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
            keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {

            self.viewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight + 5
            self.topIconConstraint.constant = 40
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide() {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.viewBottomConstraint.constant = 250
             self.topIconConstraint.constant = 150
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to look to see whether keyboardFrame overlaps the fields. If it doesn’t, don’t change the constraints.

Comment: IMO the best way to handle keyboard interaction is to use a UIScrollView. Then you can work with contentInsets instead of changing a lot of constraints. (I know this doesn't answer the question but i think it makes handling very easy)

Comment: @matt Could you give an example of how to do this?

Comment: @Teetz Well, I will not put scrollview on all screens where I will have text fields. Need to find an alternative

Comment: This is a well studied matter and has been explained here many, many times. Try searching before asking. — By the way I agree with Teetz. There’s no incentive to help someone who rejects sound advice immediately.